# How to avoid "Math." in front of every math function in C#?

Tags: c#, using, readability, simplify

I'm writing some C# heavy in mathematics. Many lines in sequence using plenty of abs(), min(), max(), sqrt(), etc.   Using C# is the plain normal way, I must preface each function with "Math."  For example

```
double x = Math.Min(1+Math.Sqrt(A+Math.Max(B1,B2)),
           Math.Min(Math.Cos(Z1),Math.Cos(Z2)));
```

I'd rather write code like in C:

```
double x = min(1+sqrt(A+max(B1,B2)), min(cos(Z1), cos(Z2)));
```

This is easier to read and looks more natural to scientists and engineers.  The normal C# way hides the good bits in a fog of "Math."

Is there a way in C# to do this?

After some googling I found an example which lead me to try

```
using min = Math.Min;
...
double x = min(a,b);
```

but the "using" statement produced an error, "System.Math.Min(decimal,decimal) is a method but is used like a type" but otherwise this looked like a good solution.  (What is 'decimal', anyway?)

Comment: "looks more natural to scientists and engineers", yes but it looks unnatural to C# programmers.

Comment: Until C# 6 ships with [`using` static members](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation), you're not able to do that.

Comment: You won't be able to do this until C# 6 ships: http://davefancher.com/2014/08/07/c-6-0-using-static/. You *could* currently write your own wrapper methods for the `Math` static methods. Neither one of the examples is exactly what'd I'd call natural or readable, though.

Comment: a `decimal` is a floating point number with a large mantissa and a small exponent.  It's used for more accurately calculating base-10 currency values.

Comment: A `decimal` actually does store decimal (instead of binary digits as float and double do). So decimal values are stored and calculated with full  precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of many solutions would be to define delegates locally. The code

```
double x = Math.Min(1+Math.Sqrt(A+Math.Max(B1,B2)),
           Math.Min(Math.Cos(Z1),Math.Cos(Z2)));
```

could be rewritten to the following implementation.

```
Func<double,double,double> min = Math.Min;
Func<double,double,double> max = Math.Max;
Func<double,double> sqrt = Math.Sqrt;
Func<double,double> cos = Math.Cos;
double x = min(1+sqrt(A+max(B1,B2)), min(cos(Z1), cos(Z2)));
```

Comment: The only problem is it forces everything to be a `double` you can't use overloads with delegates. (I was about to answer the same answer and realized that issue while typing up a example)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Very true, but using either solution would have to define the functions for every desired overload anyway.

Comment: This will harm performance significantly. Take this into consideration if that matters.

Comment: @CoryNelson Are you sure? Isn't the compiler able to optimize this by removing the delegates? If not, why not?

Comment: Not only delegate invocation harms performance, it puts load on garbags collector. In this case four objects would be constructed on heap.

Answer (score 8):

If you really care that much, you can write your own method

```
private int min(int a, int b)
{
    return Math.Min(a, b);
}
```

if you're ambitious, you can look into doing this with [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

---

Also, if you want to increase clarity, you can create a new, **descriptive** variable for each **meaningful** part, instead of your expression, instead of doing everything inline.

```
double piece2 = 1+Math.Sqrt(A+Math.Max(B1,B2));
double piece1 = Math.Min(Math.Cos(Z1),Math.Cos(Z2))
double x = min(piece1, piece2);
```

The only reason I'm naming things `piece2` and `piece2`, is because I don't actually know what your expression is supposed to calculate.  In practice, you should have more meaningful names such as `velocity`, or `incomeTaxPercentage`

Comment: wrapping the method either like this or as an extension method is the best way currently. You can do clever things with delegates but its going to be a pain to maintain. +1

Comment: You used `piece2` twice in your code and the text under, instead of `piece1` and `piece2`.

Answer (score 8):

You can't do this. At least, you *couldn't* do this before C# 6.

If you are using C# 6, you can write:

```
using static System.Math;
```

At the top of your file, which will allow you to access its static methods without using the type name (`Math`).

"using" a *method* doesn't really make any sense to the compiler, or semantically, which is why you got that error.

Finally `decimal` is another numeric type (like `double`). It just picked *that* overload of `Math.Min` when generating the error.

Comment: The syntax for this functionality has actually changed to [`using static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sf0df423.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

There is a feature for this coming in the next release of C#. See Static Using Statements [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx).

Comment: +1 for the upcoming feature, and It's marked as "already implemented" on roslyn github's : https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14

Answer (score 2):

Since the Math is a class not a namespace you can't put it as usual using,
instead you can put it like this:

using static System.Math;

It's applicable for any other class inside a namespace.

Comment: To avoid confusion, it should be noted that this is a [C# 6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx) feature.